# Php curl json post returns error

Tags: php, json, curl, digital-ocean

I am trying a little script to create and update domain names using Digital Ocean api v2 here - https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#update-a-domain-record

For some reason the response from the server is that I am missing record type.

Here is my code:

```
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer ' . file_get_contents('token.txt') );
$rawdata = array(
'type' => 'A',
'name' => 'sub',
'data' => '162.10.66.0',
'priority' => null,
'port' => null,
'weight' => null
);
$postdata = json_encode($rawdata);

$ch = curl_init(); // initiate curl
$url = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/mydomain.org/records"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTURL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTPOST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTPOSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTRETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTHTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curlexec ($ch); // execute
curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle
vardump($output); // show output
```

This is the error

```
string(81) "{"id":"unprocessable_entity","message":"Record type is not included in the list"}"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a PHP error, it's an error return by the webservice you're calling. Check their documentation to see if you're sending the right stuff to them.

Comment: I would, but there is no documentation for this particular error, and errors at all.
I can see it says I am missing record type, but I don't. I was hoping someone was facing same problem, so he can share.
What makes me think it is code error is that when I execute curl from CLI it processes properly.

Comment: I suggest you to post the CURL command line you're using from the CLI then.

Comment: Here is the CLI request:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer e7282cea8d69972acbea0305c5cd9b9e957a19bb296d728d' -d '{"type": "A","name": "home","data": "162.10.66.0","priority": null,"port": null,"weight": null}' "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/domain.org/records"`


And this is the response:

`{"domain_record":{"id":5598214,"type":"A","name":"home","data":"162.10.66.0","priority":null,"port":null,"weight":null}}`

Comment: You inadvertently posted your secret token, please invalidate it and generate a new one from your DigitalOcean panel.

Comment: I didn't - this is not valid token. Like the requested URL is example.
Should have stated the Token and request URL are changed.